# Do pointers to const vector member variable elements remain stable after the object is moved?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants, move-semantics

Consider the following C++ code:

```
class B { ... }

class A {
  public:
    // Requires vec.size() >= 1
    A(std::vector<B> vec) : vec_(vec), b_(&vec_[0]) {}
    const std::vector<B> vec_;
    const B* b_;
}
```

If I std::move an object of type A, or even copy it, will my pointer b_ to the the B object remain stable and valid? I had assumed it would because vec_ is const, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Your new constructor, taking a `std::vector<B>` instead of a `B` is risky. What if the user supplies an empty vector?

Comment: I understand, but this is a toy example to ask about pointer stability, so hopefully the invariant comment works.

Comment: If you stash a pointer to an object, that pointer will continue to point to the object for as long as the object continues to exist. This includes if you move from it, since the object still exists. Ditto if you copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't compile because you are using `Class` not `class` and because `std::vector<B>` can't be initialized with a data of type `B`. [See std::vector ctors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Now, the constant data can't be moved. If you used something like
`A a1 = std::move(a)` and `a` were a constant, the copy ctor would be invoked instead of the move ctor because `a` is constant.

How do you expect to move from a constant data? moving means stealing the contents of the data (which is constant here) and leaving it in a valid state. that stealing means you are changing the data which is constant!

Now, since your elements won't be moved by moving from `A` (because it has no move ctor), your pointer will still point to your data.

But if you do that, you will have the same pointer in the new `A` but different vectors, as follows

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class B { };

class A {
public:
    // Requires vec.size() >= 1
    A(std::vector<B> vec) : vec_(vec), b_(&vec_[0]) {}
    const std::vector<B> vec_;
    const B* b_;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<B> vec(1, B{});
    A a(vec);
    A a1 = std::move(a);
    if(a.b_ == a1.b_ && &a.vec_[0] != &a1.vec_[0])
        std::cout << "two pointers to the same location while the reality doesn't agree";

}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/r7a79K)

Comment: My bad, I've fixed the Class typo. Why can't an std::vector<B> be initialized with type B?

Comment: @Max because there is no constructor for `std::vector<B>` accepting `B`

Comment: There's no constructor for that. You could do it with `vec_(1, b)`. See [constructors for std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: Right, I thought you could use aggregate initialization for a vector in the initializer list like that, but I guess not. I've fixed this as well, but my core question is still unanswered.

Comment: @Max Actually, `vec_{b}` as you had in your first version of the question would compile but `vec_(b)` will not. The non-`const` `B* b_` will however not let you compile the program.

Comment: This is what I get when I try to write C++ without an IDE in front of me lol. `vec_(vec)` should work though right? My question still holds with `b_` made `const`.

Comment: Ok, I the edited answer makes sense. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**; You need to remove const and implement your own move constructor / move assignment operator. (Possible implementation at the end of this post).

**Explanation**

When you don't define your move or copy constructors, the compiler will try to generate them for you, unless you give it reasons not to, like declaring a custom constructor or having non-copyable data members.

Those constructors are nothing magic though so writing down what the compiler might have generated can help understand what will happen:

```
A::A(A&& other)
    : vec_(std::move(other.vec_)) // Would call vector(vector&&), if vec_ wasn't const
    , b_(std::move(other.b_))     // POD types are not moved, so this copies b_
{}
```

You have a plain-old-data member `const B b_;`. POD types are not moved, they are copied. This is not what you want so we'll fix that in our own move constructor below.

Since std::vector defines its own move constructor, `vec_(std::move(other.vec_));` *would* move the content of the vector, unless it's blocked by `const` like it is here

Assuming that's not the point of your question and you *do* want to move: you remove `const` from both data members and here's what happen:

`b_(other.b_)` remains the same (a copy), but now we get to call std::vector's move constructor. Let's look at a simplified version of vector(vector&&):

```
template <class T>
vector<T>::vector(vector&& other)
{
    this->__begin_ = __x.__begin_;       // Take other's begin
    this->__end_ = __x.__end_;           // Take other's end
    __x.__begin_ = __x.__end_ = nullptr; // REMOVE the begin/end from 'other'
}
```

So **your original `A` instance ends up with an empty `vec_` and its `b_` pointing at the new instance's vec_[0]**! If you used `b_` from the now moved original instance, you would be reading/writing in the new instance's `vec_`.

To fix that, you can define your own move constructor instead of letting the compiler generate it:

```
A::A(A&& other)
    : vec_(std::move(other.vec_))
    , b_(other.b_)
{
    other.b_ = nullptr; // effectively steal everything from 'other', including it's b_
}
```

After moving like this, your new instance effectively stole everything from the original, and it's "stable and valid". The original on the other hand is now empty.